# When can getActvity() in a retained, uncancelable DialogFragment be null?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-lifecycle, android-dialogfragment

If I have a `DialogFragment` that is retained and uncancelable, in what situations can getActivity() return null?

As far as I understand, the only ways an Activity can be destroyed are:

1. Via the back button - Which can't happen since my dialog is uncancelable
2. Via a rotate - This (I think) won't matter since my dialog is retained and the Activity will be re-attached (due to activity recreation in one main thread message) before any of my main thread callbacks are run.

The question I have is, am I missing a case? Or are my assumptions incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly an answer to your question, but I had a getActivity() to return null when used a Handler in a DialogFragment. Even if Handler had a link to DialogFragment instance it still had getActivity() as null in handleMessage() method. Would be glad to hear why does it happen.

P.S. Even more strange, what the first time this DialogFragment is created everything is fine. When we create a new instance of this DialogFragment he getActivity() in Handler starts to return null.

I suspect, that while we create a new DialogFragment, the Handler inside  somehow still attached to the old one (which already is detached and doesn't have activity)

Must admit, that my Handler is not static as recommended.

P.P.S I use compat lib for fragments

Comment: Using a Handler is always problematic since its not tied to any life-cycle except that of whichever Looper its tied to. So, yes, its very easy to leak objects using the Handler.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. After giving it some thought I think I understood my error. The handler from the first DialogFragment was registered in my service and was never unregistered. So when the message comes it goes into this handler as well. I believe it can cause a memory leak if not already :D